# Self referencing interface

Tags: c#, xml, interface

This is the kind of thing I want to do:

```
Interface IMyInterface
{
    List<IMyInterface> GetAll(string whatever)
}
```

so that classes implementing this must have a function that returns a list of their own type.
Is this even possible?
I know that - technically - a class implementing this could return a list of other classes which implement this, not necessarily the same class, but I can live with that even though it isn't ideal.

I have tried this, but I can't get the implementing class to correctly implement the method.

Comment: maybe coupling this with a generic/template would allow you to reach your goal.

Comment: Please don't post two relatively unrelated questions in one. The serialization really hasn't anything to do with the interface definition.

Comment: You should use IList rather than List

Comment: _I have tried this,_ - then please include that code with the error message.

Comment: > Is this even possible?
Yes, it is. Don't see any pb with it.
>class implementing this could return a list of other classes which implement this... though it isn't ideal
Yes, this is one of the main ideas of the interface concept. If you need one and only one class to be returned you probably don't need an interface. Or you can have one interface implementation only. 
> can't get the implementing class to correctly implement the method
Code example would be needed to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    List<IMyInterface> GetAll(string whatever);
}

public class Program : IMyInterface
{
    public string Member { get; set; }

    public List<IMyInterface> GetAll(string whatever)
    {
        return new List<IMyInterface>()
            { new Program() { Member = whatever } };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IMyInterface> all = new Program().GetAll("whatever");
        Console.WriteLine(all.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Implementing this interface is straight forward:

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl : IMyInterface
{
    public List<IMyInterface> GetAll(string whatever)
    {
        return new List<IMyInterface> { new MyInterfaceImpl(), this };
    }
}
```

Please note that the method signature needs to be exactly the same, i.e. the return type has to be `List<IMyInterface>` and not `List<MyInterfaceImpl>`.

If you want the type in the list to be the same type as the class that implements the interface, you will have to use generics:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>
{
    List<T> GetAll(string whatever)
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl : IMyInterface<MyInterfaceImpl>
{
    public List<MyInterfaceImpl> GetAll(string whatever)
    {
        return new List<MyInterfaceImpl > { new MyInterfaceImpl(), this };
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice use case for the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) ;)

Comment: Love the addition about the generics.

Comment: Making the interface self-referencing has some serious design implications I'd be wary of. You can no longer just declare a variable of type "IMyInterface". You HAVE to specify a type of interface, which generally defeats the purpose of an interface.

Comment: @EliDavis: WIth this argumentation, you disregarded all use cases of generics in interfaces...

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific, with the above code, you can't pass in anything other than an implementation of the interface.

IE:
You can't do `IMyInterface<IMyInterface> myVar;` 
There's no base case, unlike with other generic interfaces where you can fallback to `ISomething<object>`

Comment: @EliDavis: Which is precisely what we want to achieve here: Returning the class, not the interface

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what you mean by wanting to achieve "returning class, not the interface". From what I interpreted what he wanted was a "dynamic" (not sure best word here) interface method signature that's adjusted based on the implementing class. Not a restriction in the declaration of a variable type, as you can no longer just declare a variable of type "IMyInterface". It has design implications that people should be wary of if they want to use this self-referencing interface, as it affects how other people can use it, which I'd argue is substantial. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal solution. Consider you have interface `IPerson` and you want to access each parent of a person. So it would be reasonable to have interface declaration as following:

```
interface IPerson
{
    IList<IPerson> GetAllParents();
}
```

Now you are able to get parents of that parents and then get parents... Hope you got the idea. Such design is very flexible, because it allows to model deep dynamic structures using simple static models.

Implementation is very straight-forward:

```
class Person : IPerson
{
    IList<IPerson> parents;

    public Person(IList<IPerson> parents)
    {
        this.parents = parents;
    }

    public IList<IPerson> GetAllParents()
    {
        return parents;
    }
}
```

In some sense you need to create some Persons without parents (some kind of Adam and Eve) and then add childs by holding references to their parents. As you can see, my naive model can handle randomly deep family structures, while having very simple interface exposed outside.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why interface could not reference itself - no problem with below.

```
interface ITest
{
    List<ITest> GetAll(string whatever);
}

class MyClass : ITest
{
    public List<ITest> GetAll(string whatever)
    {
        return new List<ITest>();
    }
}
```