# Is it possible to define a recursive data structure using an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, recursion, design-patterns

Obviously it can be done with a `class`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```

but I'm not sure whether it can with an `interface` because I don't know of a way to refer to "the same type" within an interface.

Example:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<IMyClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I thought maybe typed parameters could make this happen, but haven't been able to imagine a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate to [Self referencing interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935957/self-referencing-interface)

Comment: Why don't you just type your code into your IDE and compile/run it to see any problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is it about your example that doesn't meet your requirements, OP?

Comment: Why would it not work with interfaces?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to return the (IEnumerable of) class implementing the interface instead of the interface itself?

If so, then you can do it like this:

```
public interface IMyClass<T>
    where T : IMyClass<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IMyClass<Foo> {
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Children {
        get => throw new NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```