# Avoid repeat type-name (class) in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

Is it possible to use the type-name (class) as a keyword in the constructor? As similar as possible in the route?

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<OrderController> _logger;

        public OrderController(ILogger<OrderController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }
}
```

I would imagine something along these

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<[controller]> _logger;

        public OrderController(ILogger<[controller]> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "primary class"?

Comment: Does this question address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935957/self-referencing-interface . Basically you'd need to implement an interface and specify the used methods/properties/whatever there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no - C# does not have a keyword or other way to avoid having to repeat a type-name (e.g. your class's name) in code. Indeed this is a pain and an annoyance, but there's no way around it (unless you count code-gen or Roslyn extensions, but let's not go there).

BTW, in this particular case (`ILogger<T>`), the `T` parameter is only used by DI to set the `Source` / `SourceContext` internal parameter of the Logger (depending on what `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` sink you're using) and it **isn't required for instances**, so you *don't* need to specify it in your field's type.

So you can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public OrderController(ILogger<OrderController> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }
    }
}
```